# HyperV VMs make my Compal router resetting connection

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, hyper-v

My ISP (Vodafone) has provided a cable modem (Compal CH7465VF) that's able to broadcast both 2,4 and 5GHz WiFi signals.
My laptop on Windows 11 runs one or two hyper-v virtual machines, both on Win11 as well. Both using an External switch, pointing out to my laptop's WiFi adapter, so the VMs could get the network connection.

Now the whole network at home runs perfectly. My work laptop runs an ssh putty tunnel and/or a few VPNs to get the work done I need. Particularly the putty tunnel is pretty sensitive to the stability of the network.
The network runs perfectly as long as I do not start any of the Hyper-V VMs. If I start them, the router irregularly seems to drop the connection and reestablish it in a few seconds. Other devices, like the TV or smartphones aren't impacted much by this because they buffer the contents streamed, but the putty tunnel drops immediately and with it all my work is gone.

If I do NOT start or run the VMs, the network remains stable for hours.

What is strange - I have connected via my smartphone's hotspot. When I run the VMs, I have no drops. I have also connected the Ethernet cable to a docking station and connected that station to my laptop. No drops as well. This made me think the problem is not with my laptop  but might be with the ISP's provided router. I have called them and they said that they are able to see very little amount of packet drops time to time, but nothing that would influence the signal reception overall. So I really think it's the router.

Could it be that the network settings in the VMs make my router think it is being hacked or something? Or that I need to reconfigure the router somehow? Or is it faulty and needs to be replaced?

Comment: What is running on the VMs? Have you tried to monitor their network usage? Are they connected with NAT?

Comment: Ask your ISP.  I have Hyper-V and Hyper-V VMs and they do not impact my ISP modem at all.

Comment: The VMs are just for either a further business testing or personal browsing. No fancy apps, just an internet browser and Discord for chatting.

Comment: The ISP says there's nothing impactful visible on his side. A tiny amount of packet drops but nothing that would influence the connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have finally figured it out.
My router is set up to act as a DHCP service.
Which I consider a completely normal setting.
I remembered I could look into the Events log within Windows. After some digging the answer was obvious.
There was an IP address conflict between my VM and my laptop. Why it happens only when on Wifi stays in the shadows.
But I have set both my VM and my host OS with a static IP and I have no more connection drops.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.